# Cloud Functions Rate Limiting IP based

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, cloud, rate-limiting

I'm setting up few cloud functions in the GCP environment and want to check if I can set the rate limiting based on IP.
Is there any way I can set it up within GCP using any other service or within cloud functions?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with a load balancer and Cloud Armor: https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rate-limiting-overview

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that with a load balancer and Cloud Armor: https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rate-limiting-overview